# CS00103 The name 'flashspeed' does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

Aparece essa mensagem de erro, o que devo fazer?

```html
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;      //
using System.Collections;


public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int startingHealth = 100;
    public int currentHealth; //qundo tomar dano valor cai
    public Slider healthSlider; //barra de vida
    public Image damageImage; //DamageImage
    public AudioClip deathClip; //audio quando morre
    public float flashspeed = 5f; //velocidade quando DamageImage pisca apagar para continuar vendo o jogo
    public Color flashColour = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.1f); //cor da damageimage red gree blue alfa (transparente)


    Animator anim; //puxar animação
    AudioSource playerAudio; //vincular audio
    PlayerMovement playerMovement; //sript playermovement (habilitar e desabilitar)
    //PlayerShooting playerShooting;
    bool isDead;
    bool damaged;


    void Awake ()  //pegando os componentes
    {
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> (); 
        playerAudio = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
        playerMovement = GetComponent <PlayerMovement> ();
        //playerShooting = GetComponentInChildren <PlayerShooting> ();
        currentHealth = startingHealth; 
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        if(damaged)
        {
            damageImage.color = flashColour;
        }
        else
        {
            damageImage.color = Color.Lerp (damageImage.color, Color.clear, flashSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        damaged = false;
    }


    public void TakeDamage (int amount) //para ser chamado em outro script - o quanto de dano player tomou
    {
        damaged = true;

        currentHealth -= amount;

        healthSlider.value = currentHealth;

        playerAudio.Play ();

        if(currentHealth <= 0 && !isDead)
        {
            Death ();
        }
    }


    void Death ()
    {
        isDead = true;

        //playerShooting.DisableEffects ();

        anim.SetTrigger ("Die");

        playerAudio.clip = deathClip;
        playerAudio.Play ();

        playerMovement.enabled = false;
        //playerShooting.enabled = false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o erro ocorre nesta linha:

```
damageImage.color = Color.Lerp (damageImage.color, Color.clear, flashSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Você irá perceber que o atributo nessa linha consta como `flashSpeed` (**com o "S" maiúsculo**). Porém, esse atributo está definido na classe da seguinte forma:

```
public float flashspeed = 5f;
```

Ou seja, **com o "S" minúsculo**.

Apesar de você (1) não ter colocado a linha onde o erro ocorreu (o que, se eu tivesse com menos boa vontade, poderia ter me motivado apenas a votar para fechar como não clara - fica a dica para tomar mais cuidado no futuro) e (2) provavelmente não ter copiado o erro corretamente, é bem provável que o erro seja esse mesmo [porque o C# é *case sensitive*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494561/why-is-c-sharp-case-sensitive) (isto é, diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Por nada. :) Se a resposta te ajudou, por favor [considere marcá-la como aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).